# Is there a adb command to get list of all the WLANs (SSIDs) that is on my phone

Tags: python, android, shell, adb

I want to check if a specific SSID (WLAN) is seen by my device. I can do it through UI where I go to the Wifi Page using selenium or UI AUtomator and get the text from there. What I am expecting is if there is a ADB shell command with which I can get the list of all the WLANs that my phone is sensing. Other alternatives are also welcome.